# How to cache third-party NPM packages using service worker in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, webpack-module-federation

I want to cache the third-party dependencies of my host-app so that the remote-apps can also use them. And I basically want to use service worker with Module federation.

I have my module federation set up and a POC app which has a Host and Remote App. But, now I want to integrate service worker also in the host level to cache dependnecies.